# Can you please tell me how can I convert this date string to total seconds in python?

Tags: python

Can you please tell me how can I convert this date string to total seconds in python?

This string format is 'years-months-days hours:mins:secs'

`'2013-01-01 01:01:01'`

Comment: Total seconds since? Is this a homework, or assigment?

Comment: but  the number of seconds since when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
import time
answer = time.mktime(time.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: he doesnt want a date object from a string.

Comment: Thanks, @randomusername. It's the answer I want.